# React bootstrap table not rendering data even though state variable is changed with new data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a react bootstrap table with is rendering the data from state. up on clicking a button, the function is making some calculations and setting the state, even after setting the state, the react bootstrap table is not showing the new data.

Here is the total code:

```
export default class MainPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.buttonRef = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      userName: "",
      passWord: "",
      productType: "",
      customer: "",
      state: "",
      city: "",
      salesAgent: "",
      salesAgentrep: "",
      phone: "",
      email: "",
      height: "Select",
      breadth: "",
      wallThickness: "",
      lbPerFt: "",
      reqQty: "",
      length: "",
      totalFootageQty: "",
      totalFreight: "",
      grade: "",
      exMillPrice: "",
      // truckWeight: "",
      totalPrice: "",
      showModel: false,
      showPropsModel: false,
      products: [],
      deliveredPerTon: null,
      tableData: [
        { dataField: "count", text: "SNO" },
        { dataField: "productType", text: "Type" },
        {
          dataField: "height",
          text: "Height",
        },
        {
          dataField: "breadth",
          text: "Breadth",
        },
        {
          dataField: "wallThickness",
          text: "WT",
        },
        {
          dataField: "lbPerFt",
          text: "LB/FT",
        },
        {
          dataField: "reqQty",
          text: "Req.Qty",
        },
        {
          dataField: "length",
          text: "Length",
        },
        {
          dataField: "totalFootageQty",
          text: "Total Footage Qty",
        },
        {
          dataField: "truckWeight",
          text: "Truck Weight",
        },
        {
          dataField: "grade",
          text: "Grade",
        },
        {
          dataField: "exMillPrice",
          text: "EX Mill",
        },
        {
          dataField: "truckFreight",
          text: "Truck Freight",
        },
        {
          dataField: "totalValue",
          text: "Total Price",
        },
        {
          dataField: "ApproxValue",
          text: "Approx Value",
        },
        {
          dataField: "",
          text: "",
          formatter: () => {
            return (
              <div style={{ marginLeft: "20px" }}>
                <button
                  onClick={() => {
                    this.setState({ showPropsModel: true });
                  }}
                  style={{
                    width: "60px",
                    height: "30px",
                    borderRadius: "0.25rem",
                    backgroundColor: "#228B22",
                    borderColor: "#228B22",
                    color: "white",
                  }}
                >
                  ADD
                </button>
              </div>
            );
          },
        },
      ],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let userName = localStorage.getItem("userName");
    let passWord = localStorage.getItem("passWord");
    this.setState({ userName: userName, passWord: passWord });
  }

  calculateWeightPerLb = (e) => {
    switch (e.target.name) {
      case "height":
        this.setState({ height: e.target.value });
        Height = e.target.value;
        break;
      case "breadth":
        this.setState({ breadth: e.target.value });
        Breadth = e.target.value;
        break;
      case "wallThickNess":
        this.setState({ wallThickness: e.target.value });
        WThick = e.target.value;
        break;
      default:
        return "";
    }
    if (Height === "" || Breadth === "" || WThick === "") {
      console.log(this.state.wallThickness);
    } else {
      let H = parseInt(Height);
      let B = parseInt(Breadth);
      let WT = parseFloat(WThick);

      let lbPerFt =
        (2 * WT * (B + H - 8 * WT) +
          3.1416 * ((2 * WT) ** 2 - (2 * WT - WT) ** 2)) *
        3.40277;
      console.log(lbPerFt);
      this.setState({ lbPerFt: lbPerFt.toFixed(2) });
    }
  };

  changePriceDetails = (e) => {
    switch (e.target.name) {
      case "exMillPerTon":
        this.setState({ exMillPrice: e.target.value });
        exMillPerTon = e.target.value;
        break;
      case "truckPerTon":
        this.setState({ truckFreight: e.target.value });
        truckFreight = e.target.value;
        break;
      default:
        return "";
    }
    if (exMillPerTon === "" || truckFreight === "") {
      return "";
    } else {
      let a = parseInt(exMillPerTon) + parseInt(truckFreight);
      this.setState({ deliveredPerTon: a });
    }
  };

  calculateFinalPricing = () => {
    let exMill = parseInt(this.state.exMillPrice) / 20;
    let truckFreight = parseInt(this.state.truckFreight) / 20;
    let deliveredPerTon = parseInt(this.state.deliveredPerTon) / 20;
    let data = this.state.tempData[0];
    data.truckFreight = truckFreight;
    data.exMillPrice = exMill;
    data.totalValue = deliveredPerTon;
    let totalValue = (deliveredPerTon / 100) * parseFloat(data.truckWeight);
    data.ApproxValue = totalValue.toFixed(2);
    let stateData = this.state.products;
    let index = data.count;
    let d = stateData.splice(index - 1, 1, data);
    this.setState({ products: d });
  };

  addItemTable = () => {
    let count = this.state.products.length + 1;
    console.log(count);
    console.log(this.state.products.length);
    let productsState = this.state.products;
    let data = {
      count: count,
      productType: this.state.productType,
      height: this.state.height,
      breadth: this.state.breadth,
      wallThickness: this.state.wallThickness,
      lbPerFt: this.state.lbPerFt,
      reqQty: this.state.reqQty,
      length: this.state.length,
      totalFootageQty: (this.state.reqQty * this.state.length).toLocaleString(),
      grade: this.state.grade,
      exMillPrice: "",
      truckWeight: this.state.reqQty * this.state.length * this.state.lbPerFt,
      totalPrice: "",
      ApproxValue: "",
      truckFreight: "",
    };
    console.log(data.truckWeight);
    productsState.push(data);
    this.setState({ products: productsState, showModel: false });
  };

  render() {
    const selectRow = {
      mode: "radio",
      clickToSelect: true,
      onSelect: (row, rowIndex) => {
        let tempData = [];
        tempData.push(row);
        this.setState({ tempData: tempData });
      },
    };
    return (
      <div style={{ marginLeft: "20px" }}>
        <div>
          <label>{JSON.stringify(this.state.products)}</label>
        </div>
        <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row" }}>
          <label className="text" style={{ marginTop: "5px" }}>
            Customer:
          </label>
          <select
            className="select"
            style={{ width: "250px", height: "40px", marginLeft: "10px" }}
            name="customer"
            id="customer"
            onChange={(e) => {
              this.setState({ customer: e.target.value });
            }}
          >
            <option>Select</option>
            <option>American Metal Corporation</option>
            <option>Arlo Steel</option>
            <option>Black Diamond</option>
          </select>

          <div
            style={{
              marginLeft: "20px",
              display: "flex",
              flexDirection: "row",
            }}
          >
            <label className="text" style={{ marginTop: "5px" }}>
              State:
            </label>
            <select
              style={{ width: "80px", height: "40px", marginLeft: "10px" }}
              className="select"
              placeholder=" Instrument Name"
              name="instrument"
              required
              onChange={(e) => {
                this.setState({ state: e.target.value });
              }}
            >
              <option>Select</option>
              <option>TX</option>
              <option>AZ</option>
              <option>AK</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div
            style={{
              marginLeft: "20px",
              display: "flex",
              flexDirection: "row",
            }}
          >
            <label className="text" style={{ marginTop: "5px" }}>
              City:
            </label>
            <select
              style={{ width: "150px", height: "40px", marginLeft: "10px" }}
              className="select"
              placeholder=" Instrument Name"
              name="city"
              required
              onChange={(e) => {
                this.setState({ city: e.target.value });
              }}
            >
              <option>Select</option>
              <option>BAYTOWN</option>
              <option>PASADENA</option>
              <option>WILMINGTON</option>
              <option>DALLAS</option>
              <option>KANSAS CITY</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row" }}>
          <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row" }}>
            <label
              className="text"
              style={{ width: "100px", marginTop: "5px" }}
            >
              Sales Agent:
            </label>
            <select
              style={{ width: "250px", height: "40px", marginLeft: "10px" }}
              className="select"
              placeholder="idNo"
              name="id"
              required
              onChange={(e) => {
                this.setState({ salesAgent: e.target.value });
              }}
            >
              <option>Select</option>
              <option>Wilson Metals</option>
              <option>Schenk Industrial</option>
              <option>Edison Tubular</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div
            style={{
              marginLeft: "20px",
              display: "flex",
              flexDirection: "row",
            }}
          >
            <label
              style={{ width: "225px", marginRight: "10px", marginTop: "5px" }}
              className="text"
            >
              Sales Agent Rep:
            </label>
            <select
              className="select"
              placeholder="idNo"
              name="id"
              required
              onChange={(e) => {
                this.setState({ salesAgentrep: e.target.value });
              }}
            >
              <option>Select</option>
              <option>CHRIS SCHENK</option>
              <option>PHIL VARGO</option>
              <option>GERG ANDERSON</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row" }}>
          <div style={{ marginRight: "10px" }}>
            <label className="text">Phone:</label>
            <label style={{ marginLeft: "10px", fontWeight: "500" }}>
              {this.state.phone}
            </label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label className="text" style={{ marginLeft: "20px" }}>
              Email:
            </label>
            <label
              style={{
                marginLeft: "10px",
                fontWeight: "500",
                width: "300px",
                // backgroundColor: "red",
              }}
            >
              {this.state.email}
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <Button
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "greenyellow",
            border: "1px solid #ced4da",
            marginTop: "30px",
          }}
          onClick={() => {
            this.setState({ showModel: true });
            console.log(this.state.showModel);
          }}
        >
          <label style={{ fontWeight: "bold", color: "black" }}>ADD S/R</label>
        </Button>
        <Button
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "greenyellow",
            border: "1px solid #ced4da",
            marginTop: "30px",
            marginLeft: "30px",
          }}
          onClick={() => {
            this.setState({ showModel: true });
            console.log(this.state.showModel);
          }}
        >
          <label style={{ fontWeight: "bold", color: "black" }}>
            ADD ROUNDS
          </label>
        </Button>
        <br />
        <br />
        <BootstrapTable
          keyField="count"
          data={this.state.products}
          columns={this.state.tableData}
          selectRow={selectRow}
        />
        <Button
          onClick={() => {
            this.setState({ products: this.state.products });
          }}
          type="submit"
          variant="primary"
          value="Upload"
        >
          Submit
        </Button>

        <Modal
          style={{ height: "50%" }}
          size="lg"
          aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
          centered
          show={this.state.showModel}
        >
          <Modal.Header
            closeButton
            onHide={() => {
              this.setState({ showModel: false });
            }}
          >
            <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
              ADD ITEM
            </Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            <div
              style={{
                display: "flex",
                flexDirection: "row",
                justifyContent: "space-evenly",
              }}
            >
              <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row" }}>
                <label
                  style={{
                    color: "darkslategray",
                    fontWeight: "bold",
                    fontSize: "17px",
                    marginRight: "10px",
                    marginTop: "5px",
                  }}
                >
                  Type:
                </label>
                <select
                  className="select"
                  style={{ width: "150px" }}
                  placeholder="Calibrated By"
                  name="calBy"
                  required
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    this.setState({ productType: e.target.value });
                  }}
                >
                  <option>Select</option>
                  <option>HSS ROUNDS</option>
                  <option>HSS SQUARE</option>
                  <option>HSS RECTANGLE</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row" }}>
                <label
                  style={{
                    color: "darkslategray",
                    fontWeight: "bold",
                    fontSize: "17px",
                    marginLeft: "20px",
                    marginTop: "5px",
                  }}
                >
                  GRADE:
                </label>

                <select
                  className="select"
                  style={{ width: "120px", marginLeft: "10px" }}
                  name="grade"
                  required
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    this.setState({ grade: e.target.value });
                  }}
                >
                  <option>Select</option>
                  <option>XA1B23</option>
                  <option>N1234D</option>
                  <option>AX21BVN</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div
              style={{
                marginTop: "15px",
                display: "flex",
                flexDirection: "row",
                justifyContent: "center",
              }}
            >
              {this.state.productType === "HSS ROUNDS" ? (
                <div
                  style={{
                    display: "flex",
                    flexDirection: "row",
                    marginRight: "10px",
                  }}
                >
                  <label
                    style={{
                      color: "darkslategray",
                      fontWeight: "bold",
                      fontSize: "17px",
                      marginTop: "5px",
                    }}
                  >
                    OD:
                  </label>
                  <select
                    style={{ width: "70px", marginLeft: "10px" }}
                    className="select"
                    name="height"
                    required
                    // onChange={this.calculateWeightPerLb}
                  >
                    <option value="Select">Select</option>
                    <option value="8.625">8.625</option>
                    <option value="9.625">9.625</option>
                    <option value="10.75">10.75</option>
                    <option value="12.75">12.75</option>
                    <option value="13.375">13.375</option>
                    <option value="14">14</option>
                    <option value="16">16</option>
                    <option value="18">18</option>
                    <option value="20">20</option>
                    <option value="24">24</option>
                    <option value="26">26</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              ) : (
                <div
                  style={{
                    display: "flex",
                    flexDirection: "row",
                    marginRight: "10px",
                  }}
                >
                  <div
                    style={{
                      display: "flex",
                      flexDirection: "row",
                      marginRight: "10px",
                    }}
                  >
                    <label
                      style={{
                        color: "darkslategray",
                        fontWeight: "bold",
                        fontSize: "17px",
                        marginTop: "5px",
                      }}
                    >
                      Height:
                    </label>
                    <select
                      ref={this.buttonRef}
                      style={{ width: "70px", marginLeft: "10px" }}
                      className="select"
                      name="height"
                      value={this.state.height}
                      onChange={this.calculateWeightPerLb}
                    >
                      <option value="Select">Select</option>
                      <option value="8">8</option>
                      <option value="10">10</option>
                      <option value="12">12</option>
                      <option value="14">14</option>
                      <option value="16">16</option>
                      <option value="18">18</option>
                      <option value="20">20</option>
                      <option value="22">22</option>
                      <option value="24">24</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row" }}>
                    <label
                      style={{
                        color: "darkslategray",
                        fontWeight: "bold",
                        fontSize: "17px",
                        marginTop: "5px",
                      }}
                    >
                      Breadth:
                    </label>
                    <select
                      className="select"
                      style={{ width: "70px", marginLeft: "10px" }}
                      name="breadth"
                      onChange={this.calculateWeightPerLb}
                    >
                      <option>Select</option>
                      <option>8</option>
                      <option>10</option>
                      <option>12</option>
                      <option>14</option>
                      <option>16</option>
                      <option>18</option>
                      <option>20</option>
                      <option>22</option>
                      <option>24</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
              )}

              <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row" }}>
                <label
                  style={{
                    color: "darkslategray",
                    fontWeight: "bold",
                    fontSize: "17px",
                    marginTop: "5px",
                  }}
                >
                  WT:
                </label>

                {this.state.productType === "HSS ROUNDS" ? (
                  <select
                    className="select"
                    style={{ width: "70px", marginLeft: "10px" }}
                    name="wallThickNess"
                    required
                    onChange={this.calculateWeightPerLb}
                  >
                    <option>Select</option>
                    <option>0.1880</option>
                    <option>0.2500</option>
                    <option>0.3220</option>
                    <option>0.3650</option>
                    <option>0.3750</option>
                    <option>0.5000</option>
                    <option>0.6250</option>
                    <option>0.7500</option>
                  </select>
                ) : (
                  <select
                    className="select"
                    style={{ width: "70px", marginLeft: "10px" }}
                    name="wallThickNess"
                    required
                    onChange={this.calculateWeightPerLb}
                  >
                    <option>Select</option>
                    <option>0.1880</option>
                    <option>0.2500</option>
                    <option>0.3130</option>
                    <option>0.3750</option>
                    <option>0.5000</option>
                    <option>0.6250</option>
                    <option>0.7500</option>
                  </select>
                )}
              </div>
            </div>

            <div
              style={{
                display: "flex",
                flexDirection: "row",
                justifyContent: "space-evenly",
                marginTop: "20px",
              }}
            >
              <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row" }}>
                <label
                  name="lbPerFt"
                  style={{
                    color: "darkslategray",
                    fontWeight: "bold",
                    fontSize: "17px",
                    marginLeft: "20px",
                    marginTop: "5px",
                  }}
                >
                  LB/FT :
                </label>
                <label
                  style={{
                    width: "60px",
                    marginLeft: "10px",
                    marginTop: "5px",
                  }}
                >
                  {this.state.lbPerFt}
                </label>
              </div>
              <div
                style={{
                  display: "flex",
                  flexDirection: "row",
                }}
              >
                <label
                  style={{
                    color: "darkslategray",
                    fontWeight: "bold",
                    fontSize: "17px",
                    marginLeft: "20px",
                    marginTop: "5px",
                  }}
                >
                  QTY :
                </label>
                <input
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    this.setState({ reqQty: e.target.value });
                    console.log(this.state.reqQty);
                  }}
                  className="textInput"
                  style={{ width: "80px", height: "40px", marginLeft: "10px" }}
                ></input>
              </div>
              <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row" }}>
                <label
                  style={{
                    color: "darkslategray",
                    fontWeight: "bold",
                    fontSize: "17px",
                    marginLeft: "20px",
                    marginTop: "5px",
                  }}
                >
                  LEN :
                </label>
                <input
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    this.setState({
                      length: e.target.value,
                    });
                  }}
                  className="textInput"
                  style={{ width: "80px", height: "40px", marginLeft: "10px" }}
                ></input>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button onClick={this.addItemTable}>Add ITEM</Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
        <Modal
          show={this.state.showPropsModel}
          onHide={() => {
            this.setState({ showPropsModel: false });
          }}
        >
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>Price Info</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            <div
              style={{
                display: "flex",
                flexDirection: "row",
                justifyContent: "space-evenly",
                marginTop: "20px",
              }}
            >
              <div
                style={{
                  display: "flex",
                  flexDirection: "row",
                }}
              >
                <label
                  style={{
                    color: "darkslategray",
                    fontWeight: "bold",
                    fontSize: "17px",
                    marginLeft: "20px",
                    marginTop: "5px",
                  }}
                >
                  Ex-Mill($/ton) :
                </label>
                <input
                  name="exMillPerTon"
                  onChange={this.changePriceDetails}
                  className="textInput"
                  style={{ width: "80px", height: "40px", marginLeft: "10px" }}
                ></input>
              </div>
              <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row" }}>
                <label
                  style={{
                    color: "darkslategray",
                    fontWeight: "bold",
                    fontSize: "17px",
                    marginLeft: "20px",
                    marginTop: "5px",
                  }}
                >
                  Truck($/ton) :
                </label>
                <input
                  name="truckPerTon"
                  onChange={this.changePriceDetails}
                  className="textInput"
                  style={{ width: "80px", height: "40px", marginLeft: "10px" }}
                ></input>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div
              style={{
                display: "flex",
                flexDirection: "row",
                marginTop: "10px",
              }}
            >
              <label
                style={{
                  color: "darkslategray",
                  fontWeight: "bold",
                  fontSize: "17px",
                  marginLeft: "20px",
                  marginTop: "5px",
                }}
              >
                Delivered($/ton) :
              </label>
              <label
                name="deliveredPerTon"
                style={{
                  width: "60px",
                  marginLeft: "10px",
                  marginTop: "5px",
                }}
              >
                {this.state.deliveredPerTon}
              </label>
            </div>
          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button onClick={this.calculateFinalPricing} variant="primary">
              Save Changes
            </Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

upon clicking the this.calculateFinalPricing function, the function is setting up the state. but react bootstrap table is not showing up the new data.

```
 calculateFinalPricing = () => {
    let exMill = parseInt(this.state.exMillPrice) / 20;
    let truckFreight = parseInt(this.state.truckFreight) / 20;
    let deliveredPerTon = parseInt(this.state.deliveredPerTon) / 20;
    let data = this.state.tempData[0];
    data.truckFreight = truckFreight;
    data.exMillPrice = exMill;
    data.totalValue = deliveredPerTon;
    let totalValue = (deliveredPerTon / 100) * parseFloat(data.truckWeight);
    data.ApproxValue = totalValue.toFixed(2);
    let stateData = this.state.products;
    let index = data.count;
    let d = stateData.splice(index - 1, 1, data);
    this.setState({ products: d });
  };
```

this is the react bootstrap table component where data is taken from this.state.products.

```
<BootstrapTable
          keyField="count"
          data={this.state.products}
          columns={this.state.tableData}
          selectRow={selectRow}
        />
```

Comment: This seems a bit of a code dump, and it's also incomplete so we're not able to copy/paste it into an IDE to run it. Do you mind either tightening this up to a minimal & complete code example, or adding the missing declarations so it's complete & reproducible?